# Disable values in dropdown button

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown

I have some values in a dropdown list but I want to disable some of them.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) I found a solution like if we add disabled style to `<a>` it will be disabled. I tried same for dropdown element B but it didn't work.

Help if I am  wrong somewhere.

Please find below code snippet for reference,

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="fa fa-plus plusIcon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <span class=" fa fa-cube dropdown-header"> Dropdown Values </span>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <a class="dropdown-item">A</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item disabled">B</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try it with list items instead. working for me

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
      <li class="dfgdfgdf disabled"><a href="#">Disabled</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your lib js and css reference
2. just add `href="#"`

It's working fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="fa fa-plus plusIcon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <span class=" fa fa-cube dropdown-header"> Dropdown Values </span>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```